# TestNG suite runs only the first class but did not even consider the second test class. Dont know why its not running or skipping or failing

Tags: selenium, testng

I have two classes as test class and one base class in TestNG + Java.

I have created a TestNG suite so that it will run both test classes. Don't know why but it's only running the first one. but for the second class, there is no mark for skipped/failed in the output console. What could be the reason?

This is my TestNG suite: (testng.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
<!--       <class name="testCases.StudentRegistrationForm"/> -->
       <class name="testCases.NewsTest"/> 
      <class name="testCases.StudentRegistrationForm"/> 
      
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

And my console output is :

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.3.0
1642804333177   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:39421
1642804333378   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "--marionette" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\jeyan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofileU67BO8"
1642804333719   Marionette  INFO    Marionette enabled
console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new NotFoundError("Could not open the file at C:\\Users\\jeyan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofileU67BO8\\search.json.mozlz4", (void 0)))
1642804335589   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 58948
1642804336079   RemoteAgent WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Jan 22, 2022 4:02:16 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
JavaScript error: https://static.files.bbci.co.uk/orbit/7e4d464d9adf1a097178544b394185aa/js/require.min.js, line 1: Error: Script error for "idcta-v2/config", needed by: idcta-v2/analytics, idcta-v2/id-config
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: Add `verbose="10"` as attribute to your `<test` tag in xml. This will print testng detailed logs.

Comment: How did you run this `testng.xml` file? Also, do you want them to run in parallel or in sequence?